# "Causa est" in this sentence

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin

How would I translate this sentence to make sense of the "causa est?" I feel that part of it might have to do with the best choice of word for "dicit" as well.

> Divinitas enim in prima notione & concepto suo, dicit eminentiam &
> excellentiam in omni genere perfectionis, quae omnium rerum, ipsiusque
> creature rationalis, sive hominis **causa est**. Creatura vero
> rationalis, dicit intrinsece dependentiam a causa ista, secundum se
> totam, & totum sui, & capacitatem, sive idoneitatem ad religionem
> exercendam.

Answer (score 11):

The *est* is the verb of the relative clause started by *quae*; it's used as a copula, and *causa* is the predicate nominative (complement). All the genitives – *omnium rerum*, *ipsiusque creature* (= *creaturae*) *rationalis*, and *hominis* – depend on *causa*.

> ...which is the cause of all things, and of the rational creature itself (or humankind).

I would translate *dicit* here as 'means' or 'signifies.'

> Divinity means eminence and excellence...